# can a udacity test be broken

Tags: python, testing, binary-search

I was Implementing a binary search function using python here is my code

```
def binary_search(input_array, value):
    n = round(len(input_array)/2)
    #print(n)
    while n < len(input_array) and n>0:
        if input_array[n]< value:
            n = n + round(n/2)
            #print(n)
        elif input_array[n] > value:
            n = n - round(n/2)
            #print(n)
        elif input_array[n] == value:
            return n
    return -1
```

here are the test cases

```
test_list = [1,3,9,11,15,19,29]
test_val1 = 25
test_val2 = 15
print(binary_search(test_list, test_val1)) 
print(binary_search(test_list, test_val2))
```

This code is working fine in my shell and in VSCode python debugger.

however in the Udacity course test i am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "vm_main.py", line 31, in <module> import main File "/tmp/workspaces/c1b619f1-2167-4be2-8d76-c9876c79f7a6/main.py", line 2, in <module> import studentMain File "/tmp/workspaces/c1b619f1-2167-4be2-8d76-c9876c79f7a6/studentMain.py", line 1, in <module> import algorithmsP5 File "/tmp/workspaces/c1b619f1-2167-4be2-8d76-c9876c79f7a6/algorithmsP5.py", line 30, in <module> print binary_search(test_list, test_val1) File "/tmp/workspaces/c1b619f1-2167-4be2-8d76-c9876c79f7a6/algorithmsP5.py", line 17, in binary_search if input_array[n]< value: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

so it states that there is a type error and that list indices must be integers not floats

but n is `round(len(input_array)/2)` and `round()` should return an integer value

here are the docs

```
round(number, ndigits=None)
Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input.

For the built-in types supporting round(), values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2). Any integer value is valid for ndigits (positive, zero, or negative). The return value is an integer if ndigits is omitted or None. Otherwise, the return value has the same type as number.
```

it states that if ndigits is omitted or None the return value is an integer.

so is the udacity test broken or am I missing out something

Comment: There are probably test cases where using `round` (which rounds `x.5` to the nearest even integer, rather than always `x` or always `x + 1`) would break binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the udacity test may be using Python 2.x. Compare Python 3:

```
Python 3.11.2 (main, Feb  8 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 12.2.1 20221121 (Red Hat 12.2.1-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> round(1/2)
0
```

With Python 2:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> round(1/2)
0.0
```

---

@KellyBundy is correct and the best solution is to explicitly use integer division rather than using `round()`. You could explicitly convert the return value of `round` to an integer (`int(round(1/2))`), but that seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Worse, [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) doesn't always round down.

Comment: @chepner Does anybody expect that? Who thinks `round(0.99)` should round down?

Comment: We're talking about fractions with a denominator of 2, not arbitrary floats. Nobody said `round(0.99)` would round down. But without knowing the integer part of the original number, you can't predict which way `round` will round. One might expect `x + .5` to always round up or always round down.

Comment: I wanted my algorithm to round up my values so if the input is an odd number I would be exactly at the middle. and round() will round will always the half up. which is what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Then `int(round(...))` may be what you want after all.

Comment: @KarimMaged As the doc and chepner said, `round` does ***not*** always round .5 up. If you do want to always round up, use `//` with adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

From `round`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#round):

> The result is a floating point number.

You should use floor division `//` instead of rounding anyway.

Comment: I tried to use the floor division before asking the question and I got a keyboard interrupt error. I also tried wrapping my round inside an int() to make sure the number would be an integer and still got the keyboard interrupt error. However both methods worked in my shell

Comment: @KarimMaged That error is intended for a person stopping the program by pressing certain keyboard keys. Surely Udacity doesn't have real people running your code, so that seems like an abuse. Anyway, it probably means that you have an infinite loop for some inputs, and Udacity uses that error to kill your program when it takes too long.